# How to modify Makefile to support cross compilation?

Tags: c++, makefile, cross-compiling

I have the following Makefile:

```
CC=g++

top_srcdir=$(SRC_DIR)/cpp/src/

INCLUDES:= -I $(top_srcdir) -I $(top_srcdir)command_classes -I $(top_srcdir)platform -I $(top_srcdir)value_classes
LIBS:= -lopenzwave -lpthread -ludev
LDFLAGS += -L$(SRC_DIR) -Wl,-R$(SRC_DIR) '-Wl,-R$$ORIGIN'

all:    ozw

ozw: Main.cpp
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c Main.cpp -o ozw-power-on-off.o
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS) ozw-power-on-off.o -o ozw-power-on-off.out

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.out
```

I execute it with the following command:

```
  make ARCH=$TARGET_ARCH \
       CROSS_COMPILE=$TARGET_PREFIX \
       SRC_DIR=$ROOT/$PKG_BUILD
```

But it ignores `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE` values. I tried to replace `$(CC)` with `$(MAKE)` and added `-$(MAKEFLAGS)`, but it was saying `Nothing to be done for 'Main.cpp'`.

How can I fix it and add cross compilation support?

Comment: Why not read someone else's Makefile and determine how they've done it? There are thousands if not millions out there that you could study.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit probably because it is hard to see if a given makefile can actually be use for cross-compilation

Comment: @umläute: How so? Just read the `README` for that project...

Comment: sure; also there are zillions of `autotools` project that (theoretically) allow cross-compilation, even though it's not mentioned in the `README`s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible example of something I would try is below assuming $ARCH get's mapped to "arm" in this trivial example. I haven't tested it, but have done something similar before.

```
CC=g++
CC-arm=arm-g++

ozw: Main.cpp
    $(CC-$(ARCH)) $(INCLUDES) -c Main.cpp -o ozw-power-on-off.o
    $(CC-$(ARCH)) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS) ozw-power-on-off.o -o ozw-power-on-off.out
```

edit: This assumes that the tool chain exists in your path.
edit: Might also modify it such that CC=$(PREFIX)-g++ it all depends on what you how what you pass into it maps against your tool chains naming convention.

Comment: Thanks, usage of `CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)g++` helped.

Answer (score 11):

The *things* you are passing to `make` (e.g. `ARCH=$TARGET_ARCH`) are really just `Makefile variables`.
`make` doesn't know at all that they are related to *cross-compilation* (this is just something that you associate in your brain). E.g.

```
 $ cat Makefile
 ARCH=pdp-11
 foo:
    @echo arch: $ARCH
 $ make
 arch: pdp-11
 $ make ARCH=le-corbusier
 arch: le-corbusier
```

The standard way to do cross-compilation is to just override the compiler/linker. E.g. the following would cross-compile for `i686-w64-mingw32`:

```
  $ cat Makefile
  .PHONY: ozw
  owz: ozw-power-on-off.out
  ozw-power-on-off.o: Main.cpp
      $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
  ozw-power-on-off.out: ozw-power-on-off.o
      $(CXX) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS)

  $ make CXX=i686-w64-mingw32-g++
```

### a few notes

Your makefile has a number of issues...

#### variable names

`CC` is the standard variable for the *C-Compiler*; for a *C++-compiler* use `CXX`

#### linking order matters

Modern linkers will [discard unused symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/), leading to possible linker errors if you don't get the order right. Therefore you should puts the `$(LIBS)` variable at the very end of your linker-invocation

#### declare dependencies

The power of `make` really is in the ability to resolve dependencies (finding out which parts of the build tree need to be recompiled when a few files have changed). For this to work you need to write rules that encode these dependencies - rather than conjure arbitrary target names and force to rebuild everything.